# Plotting Treasury Yield Curve, how to overlay two yield curves using matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to create a graph of the [treasury yield curve](http://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/Pages/Historic-Yield-Data-Visualization.aspx) to compare the rates from two separate dates. I am having difficulty with combining the two curves and creating a clean graph. **My question**:  how do I plot the two yield curves together, with the yields (rates) are on the y-axis, and the maturities (2yr, 5yr, 10yr, 20yr, 30yr) are on the x-axis?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import pandas.io.data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import quandl as q
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

treasury = q.get("USTREASURY/YIELD", trim_start="2000-01-01", returns="pandas")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

treas = DataFrame(treasury)
treas.drop(treas.columns[[0,1,2,3,5,7]], axis=1, inplace=True)
today = treas.iloc[-1:]
first = treas.iloc[:1]
first = first.T
today = today.T

ax.plot(first, 'o')
ax.plot(today, 'x')

#first.plot(marker='o')
#today.plot(marker='o')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you include the current plot and explain what you are expecting instead?

Comment: Basically, I want it to look just like the yield curve from the treasury.gov link I added.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the points joined by a line, or is there more to it than that?

Comment: Yes, I want the points joined by a line, but my main problem is they aren't plotting the way I had hoped (the yield on the y-axis, and the maturity on the x-axis). Right now, it is flipped.

Comment: `ax.plot(maturity, yield, '-o')`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import quandl as ql
#import Quandl as ql
%matplotlib inline

yield_ = ql.get("USTREASURY/YIELD")
today = yield_.iloc[-1,:]
month_ago = yield_.iloc[-30,:]
df = pd.concat([today, month_ago], axis=1)
df.columns = ['today', 'month_ago']

df.plot(style={'today': 'ro-', 'month_ago': 'bx--'}
        ,title='Treasury Yield Curve, %');
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

FYI:
I'm using python 3.8 and spyder with anaconda. I spent a lot of time troubleshooting the 'module not found error for Quandl only to discover it should be quandl (lowercase).

Comment: Great point. They changed it from Quandl to quandl shortly after this question was asked, I think sometime in 2016.