# matplotlib US Treasury yield curve

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, finance

I'm currently trying to build a dataframe consisting of daily US Treasury Rates. As you can see, pandas automatically formats the columns so that they're in order, which clearly I do not want. Here's some of my code. I only needed to do a small example in order to show the problem I'm having.

```
import quandl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

One_Month = quandl.get('FRED/DGS1MO')
```

^^ Repeated for all rates

```
Yield_Curve = pd.DataFrame({'1m': One_Month['Value'], '3m': Three_Month['Value'], '1yr': One_Year['Value']})
Yield_Curve.loc['2017-06-22'].plot()
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
Yield_Curve.tail()


             1m      1yr     3m
Date            
2017-06-16  0.85    1.21    1.03
2017-06-19  0.85    1.22    1.02
2017-06-20  0.88    1.22    1.01
2017-06-21  0.85    1.22    0.99
2017-06-22  0.80    1.22    0.96
```

As I said, I only added three rates to the dataframe but obviously the two year, three year, and five year rates will cause a problem as well.

I did some searching and saw this post: 
[Plotting Treasury Yield Curve, how to overlay two yield curves using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33017564/plotting-treasury-yield-curve-how-to-overlay-two-yield-curves-using-matplotlib)

While using the code in the last post clearly works, I'd rather be able to keep my current datasets (One_Month, Three_Month....) to do this since I use them for other analyses as well.

Question: Is there a way for me to lock the column order?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `pandas-datareader` you can specify the symbols as one list.  And in addition to using `reindex_axis` as suggested by @Andrew L, you can also just pass a list of ordered columns with two brackets, see final line below, to specify column order.

```
from pandas_datareader.data import DataReader as dr
syms = ['DGS10', 'DGS5', 'DGS2', 'DGS1MO', 'DGS3MO']
yc = dr(syms, 'fred') # could specify start date with start param here
names = dict(zip(syms, ['10yr', '5yr', '2yr', '1m', '3m']))
yc = yc.rename(columns=names)
yc = yc[['1m', '3m', '2yr', '5yr', '10yr']]

print(yc)
              1m    3m   2yr   5yr  10yr
DATE                                    
2010-01-01   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2010-01-04  0.05  0.08  1.09  2.65  3.85
2010-01-05  0.03  0.07  1.01  2.56  3.77
2010-01-06  0.03  0.06  1.01  2.60  3.85
2010-01-07  0.02  0.05  1.03  2.62  3.85
         ...   ...   ...   ...   ...
2017-06-16  0.85  1.03  1.32  1.75  2.16
2017-06-19  0.85  1.02  1.36  1.80  2.19
2017-06-20  0.88  1.01  1.36  1.77  2.16
2017-06-21  0.85  0.99  1.36  1.78  2.16
2017-06-22  0.80  0.96  1.34  1.76  2.15

yc.loc['2016-06-01'].plot(label='Jun 1')
yc.loc['2016-06-02'].plot(label='Jun 2')
plt.legend(loc=0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking to define the column ordering, you can use `reindex_axis()`:

```
df = df.reindex_axis(labels=['1m', '3m', '1yr'], axis=1)

df
              1m    3m   1yr
Date                        
2017-06-16  0.85  1.03  1.21
2017-06-19  0.85  1.02  1.22
2017-06-20  0.88  1.01  1.22
2017-06-21  0.85  0.99  1.22
2017-06-22  0.80  0.96  1.22
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to change original column order in spite of you need sorted column along to finance notation, I guess you should make your own customized column order like below.

```
fi_col = df.columns.str.extract('(\d)(\D+)', expand=True).sort_values([1, 0]).reset_index(drop=True)
fi_col = fi_col[0] + fi_col[1]

print(df[fi_col])

              1m    3m   1yr
Date                        
2017-06-16  0.85  1.03  1.21
2017-06-19  0.85  1.02  1.22
2017-06-20  0.88  1.01  1.22
2017-06-21  0.85  0.99  1.22
2017-06-22  0.80  0.96  1.22
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also pull all the historical rates directly from the US Treasury's website (updated daily):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://data.treasury.gov/feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData').text,'lxml')
table = soup.find_all('m:properties')
tbondvalues = []
for i in table:
    tbondvalues.append([i.find('d:new_date').text[:10],i.find('d:bc_1month').text,i.find('d:bc_2month').text,i.find('d:bc_3month').text,i.find('d:bc_6month').text,i.find('d:bc_1year').text,i.find('d:bc_2year').text,i.find('d:bc_3year').text,i.find('d:bc_5year').text,i.find('d:bc_10year').text,i.find('d:bc_20year').text,i.find('d:bc_30year').text])
ustcurve = pd.DataFrame(tbondvalues,columns=['date','1m','2m','3m','6m','1y','2y','3y','5y','10y','20y','30y'])
ustcurve.iloc[:,1:] = ustcurve.iloc[:,1:].apply(pd.to_numeric)/100
ustcurve['date'] = pd.to_datetime(ustcurve['date'])
```